# App suspended from Google play but cannot update the app to rectify it

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

My app got suspended from Google Play due to the impersonation policy.

I want to fix this, but finding all of my console controls are disabled (can't update the store listing, the build etc.).

I sent in an appeal and just tried to describe my issue to Google. But they weren't helpful. They sent in a copy paste message saying your app is still violating, with no regards with my actual content of the message asking if I can update my app.

Anyone else had this issue? Not sure how to contact Google to actually get someone to read and fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try again later , as sometime they might got delay on replying as they are busy at the moment